# deploy node js API with ownCloud

Tags: node.js, api, owncloud

I want to deploy NodeJS API with ownCloud, is there any help regarding this?   I have done googling but no satisfied answer found. Please help me.

Comment: what you did till now? What answers?

Comment: Removed unnecessary "thank you", which doesn't contribute to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the server ? 
Overall, you just have to connect to server using ssh or putty.

1. Install node, and upload your nodejs API
2. upload your DB, and make sure connect to nodejs API
3. run your api for test